# Problema al pedir una consulta y buscar un elemento en arrays y en bucles

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, while

Hola verán es que estoy haciendo un programa donde da a elegir tres opciones:

La primera opción es para que el usuario meta su DNI y el número de entradas (que no puede ser mayor que 4 ya que si lo es saldrá un error y volverá al menú principal) ni tampoco que el DNI que se meta ya esté en el array. El programa estará pidiendo DNI y reservas hasta 12 intentos. Si se va por el camino correcto (DNI que no estuviese antes en el array y el num de reservas menor o igual que 4 por cada vez) pues el DNI se guarda en el array de dni's y el numero de reserva se guarda en el array de reservas y acto seguido se actualiza la posición (que también podría haber utilizado un for pero opté por el while y meter el contador a mano).

La segunda opción introduzco una posición y me devolverá el programa los datos introducidos tanto en el array de los dni's y en el de reservas que estén en esa posición (creo que está mal).

La tercera opción se sale del programa.

He visto que al meterme en una opción al volver al menú principal no me deja meterme de nuevo en otra ya que se repetirá el menú una y otra vez. También cuando meto un dni y compruebo si ya está guardado pues me sale siempre el mensaje de que "ya está guardado"

Y la segunda opción me da que está mal de principios porque no creo que sea tan fácil hacerlo así, sino puedo poner en su lugar un for para que muestre todos los dnis y reservas.

```
  //datos
        String dni = "xxxxxxxx";
        int entrada, cont = 0, reserva = 0, resp, opcion, pos = 0;

        String arraydni[] = new String[12];                 //Inicializamos los 2 arrays
        int reservarray[] = new int[12];
        boolean seguir = true, continuacion = true, dnigual = false;
        //inicialización Scanner
        Scanner entradaTeclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        //código

        do {
            //Mostramos menú al usuario para que pueda elegir una opción
            System.out.println("### REALIZACIÓN DE RESERVAS ###");

            System.out.println("1.Realizar una reserva: ");
            System.out.println("2.Consultar una reserva: ");
            System.out.println("3.Salir del programa");
            System.out.print("Introduzca su opción: ");
            opcion = entradaTeclado.nextInt();

            Scanner entradaX = new Scanner(System.in);
            switch (opcion) {

                case 1:

                    while (seguir == true && reserva<12) {

                        System.out.print("Introduzca el DNI: ");
                        dni = entradaX.nextLine();

                        for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {          //Comprobamos si ya existía un dni igual al que vamos a meter
                            if (arraydni[i].equals(dni)) {
                                dnigual = true;
                            } else {

                            }
                        }

                        if (dnigual = true) {               //Si introduzco un dni no válido ya ni me deja continuar con reservas
                            System.out.println("Lo sentimos, no puede introducir un dni igual al que ya está");
                        }

                        else {                              //Si introduzco un dni válido

                        arraydni[pos] = dni;                //metemos el dni en el array

                        System.out.print("¿Cuantas entradas quiere usted?: ");
                        entrada = entradaTeclado.nextInt();

                        reserva++;

                        if (entrada > 4) {
                            System.out.println("ERROR No puede reservar más entradas que 4");
                            seguir = false;                 //Si hay más de 4 entradas no se actualiza el array de reservas
                        }

                        else {
                            reservarray[pos] = entrada;     //introducimos el numero de entradas en el array

                            pos++;                          //####### actualizamos los dos arrays!!!!!!! #######

                        }

                        }
                        //Preguntar al usuario si desea seguir
                        System.out.print("Desea seguir? (0/1), sino será retornado al menú principal: ");
                        resp = entradaTeclado.nextInt();
                        if (resp == 0) {
                            seguir = false;
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    while (seguir == true) {
                        System.out.print("Consulta:");              //Introducimos un numero de posición y nos dará los datos-
                        pos = entradaTeclado.nextInt();             //-de los dos arrays en esa posición (DNI y numero de entradas)
                        System.out.println("El DNI" + arraydni[pos] + " y el numero de reservas que hizo fue " + reservarray[pos]);
                        System.out.println("Desea realizar otra consulta (0/1)? ");
                        opcion = entradaTeclado.nextInt();
                        if (opcion == 0) {
                            seguir = false;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Gracias por haber disfrutado del programa");
                    continuacion = false;
                    break;
            }
        } while (continuacion == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Estoy haciendo exactamente el mismo trabajo que tú y también he pedido ayuda, pero creo que no me expresé correctamente. La verdad es que me cuesta entender tu código, pero lo ejecuté y depuré y parece que al igual que yo tu problema principal es la comprobación del DNI con el for. A mi, salvando ese detalle que me está desesperando, todo lo demás me va bien, te paso mi código para ver si entiendes como solucionar lo demás, aunque en mi caso esructuré el programa de una forma totalmente diferente.
En el caso del menú, también hice un do while, pero le indiqué que se volviera a ejecutar salvo que se pulse específicamente la opción de salir.

```
    int opc, i = 0;
    long disp = 12, ent, dni, resul = 0;
    long a1[] = new long[12];
    long a2[] = new long[12];

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    /*Bucle donde repetimos el programa hasta que se pulse salir*/
    do {
        /*Mostramos el menú*/
        System.out.println("VENTA DE ENTRADAS");
        System.out.println("1. HACER RESERVAS");
        System.out.println("2. VER RESERVAS");
        System.out.println("3. SALIR");
        opc = teclado.nextInt();
        /*Diferentes opciones*/
        switch (opc) {
            case 1:
                /*Primero comprobamos que haya entradas disponibles*/
                if (disp > 0) {
                    System.out.println("¿Cuántas entradas quiere?");
                    ent = teclado.nextInt();
                    /*Comprobamos que no pida más de 4*/
                    if (ent <= 4) {
                        /*Comprobamos que hay tantas disponibles como pide*/
                        if (ent <= disp) {
                            System.out.println("Introduzca su DNI");
                            dni = teclado.nextInt();
                            /*Comprobamos que el DNI esté o no en el array*/
                            for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                                if (dni == a1[i]) {
                                    /*Si lo está, comprobamos cuántas entradas ha pedido anteriormente*/
                                    resul = a2[i] + ent;
                                }

                            }

                            /*Si la suma de la cantidad que pide es igual o menor a 4, se suma*/
                            if (resul <= 4) {
                                a2[i] = resul;
                                /*Se le resta la compra al total para que se reflejen las entradas disponibles*/
                                disp = disp - ent;
                            }
                            /*Si el dni es nuevo, se añade al array 1 con su compra de entradas en el array2*/
                            if (dni != a1[i]) {
                                a1[i] = dni;
                                a2[i] = ent;
                                disp = disp - ent;
                            }

                            /*Si el disponible de entradas es inferior a la petición, damos error*/
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("NO QUEDAN SUFICIENTES ENTRADAS DISPONIBLES");
                        }
                        /*Si inentan comprar más de 4 entradas por persona, damos error*/
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("NO SE PUEDEN COMPRAR MÁS DE 4 ENTRADAS POR PERSONA");
                    }
                    /*Si las entradas están agotadas, lo indicamos al pulsar "compra de entradas"*/
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ENTRADAS AGOTADAS");
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                /*Mostramos las entradas disponibles*/
                System.out.println("Entradas disponibles: " + disp);
                /*Bucle para que muestre todos los DNI con sus compras*/
                for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                    System.out.println("DNI: " + a1[i] + " " + "Entradas" + a2[i]);
                    break;
                }
        }
    } while (opc != 3);

}
```

}

Comment: Entonces es una respuesta a la pregunta hecha?

Comment: es una respuesta parcial

Comment: ¿Tienes el mismo problema?

¿No hay respuesta a cierta pregunta y tienes el mismo problema? Ayúdanos a encontrar una solución. Investiga el problema y aporta los resultados de tu investigación con información adicional como una respuesta parcial. De esa forma, aunque no se obtenga una respuesta, la persona siguiente tendrá más con que hacerle frente al desafío. Podrás también votar a favor la pregunta u ofrecer una recompensa para que la pregunta reciba más atención.